# C# Listview in Explorer window theme draws vertical lines

Tags: c#, listview

I've set my Listview to look same as Windows Explorer using SetWindowTheme API, but doing that It also paints vertical lines under column headers. Is there any chance to remove this vertical lines ? See picture under to see lines:

[image]

I set windows theme using this line :

```
SetWindowTheme(listview1.Handle, "explorer", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lines are actually drawn by the `explorer` visual style (uxtheme.dll) itself.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `listview1.GridLines = false`.

Note that this will have no effect unless the `listView1.View` property is set to `View.Details`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.gridlines(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It doesn't work